# Can I embed a page from a website into a LaTeX document?

Tags: embedding

I am familiar with how to embed images into a LaTeX document, and have read some about embedding audio and video using the multimedia package, but what I want to do is a bit more complicated. The closest thing to what I want to do, that I could find documentation for, is a package that allows one to embed an interactive Google map into a LaTeX document, but that package seems specific to Google maps.

In particular, I'm using the site [www.desmos.com](http://www.desmos.com) to create some graphs with slideable parameters. I'm writing some notes to share with my collaborators and I was wondering if, rather than just linking to the website, I can put a frame of the image along with all the slidable parameters, right into my document.

The site makes available HTML code for en embedding using the `iframe` tag. Is there a package that allows me to use this? Is there some other way to do it?

I realize I could also settle for putting a link into the document and taking screenshot, but would like to know if the interactive content can be included directly.

Comment: latex normally generates pdf, you can't put a general html/javascript page in a pdf file. So LaTeX isn't really an issue unless you are not using tex but one of the convertors to html eg tex4ht in which case it would be simple just to add the generated iframe to any html generated from the latex, but that isn't really a latex question.

Comment: For this scenario, it's certainly easier to write everything in html and embed latex with [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the comment, this answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

latex normally generates pdf, you can't put a general html/javascript page in a pdf file. So LaTeX isn't really an issue unless you are not using tex but one of the convertors to html eg tex4ht in which case it would be simple just to add the generated iframe to any html generated from the latex, but that isn't really a latex question.